# How to get view model with hilt outside activity in jetpack compose

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt, android-navigation-graph

So I have a kotlin file named "ListScreen"  (it's not a class! just a .kt file with composable functions) and I'm handling transactions with compose navigation graph system.
Right now I'm trying to access my `ViewModel` which is indicated with `@HiltViewModel` from the "ListScreen" file.
Apparently, in the past, there was a way to access `ViewModels` with hilt like this:
`viewModel: PokemonListViewModel = hiltNavGraphViewModels()`
but this isn't working right now. how can I do it?

here's my `ViewModel` class:

```
@HiltViewModel
class PokemonListViewModel @Inject constructor(
private val repository: PokemonRepository
) : ViewModel() {


fun calcDominantColor(
    drawable: Drawable,
    onFinish: (Color) -> Unit
) {
    val bmp = (drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)

    Palette.from(bmp).generate { palette ->
        palette?.dominantSwatch?.rgb?.let {
            onFinish(Color(it))

        }

    }
}
}
```

and here's the block of code which isn't working:

```
 @Composable
fun PokedexEntry(
    entry: PokedexListEntry,
    navController: NavController,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: PokemonListViewModel = hiltNavGraphViewModels()

)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hiltNavGraphViewModels() is now depcecated. Use hiltViewModel() instead.

From android documentation.

```
Deprecated: Use hiltViewModel() instead.. Replace with: "hiltViewModel()".
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/hilt/navigation/compose/package-summary#hiltNavGraphViewModel()

Comment: Well that deprecation was really fast. Surprised me, even for google

Comment: Yeah since compose isn't stable yet, anything can happen.